# Implement a Register Allocator in LLVM

Tags: c++, llvm, compiler-optimization, register-allocation

I'm working on my project for completion undergraduate courses, consisting of an experimental analysis of registers allocation algorithms. For this task, I am using the set of tools from the LLVM project.

However, I have read the documentation of the LLVM project and not yet found a way to put the pieces of the puzzle together. So far I know:

- As passes work as engage them to LLVM and know I must implement MachineFunctionPass [pass](http://llvm.org/docs/WritingAnLLVMPass.html).
- I follow some suggestions to look at the [Basic Allocator](http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/RegAllocBasic_8cpp.html) code, but could not understand much.

The allocator I intend to implement is based on graph coloring heuristics, as the theory of operation of such methods I’m well aware.

So I look for is some sort of "How to", a defined set of steps to implement such allocator. It sounds like carelessness, but I have to deliver the work in about six months and I'm a little confused.

If anyone can give me some guidance or reference to any supporting material (besides the own documentation), I would be grateful.

My English may be a little wrong, I am a Brazilian student.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, after a while I have finished my project and have written an tutorial of How to write an LLVM register allocator using the `RegAllocBase` interface.

The tutorial have been written in `reStructuredText` and it's available on GitHub: https://github.com/nael8r/How-To-Write-An-LLVM-Register-Allocator